# Strange printf and puts statements explained

Tags: c, printf, puts

I came across these two statements in a SNS photo album, with the title "the most elegant way of output I ever met" or something.

Here are the two statements:

```
printf("%d%c", a, " \n"[i==n]);
puts("YES\0No"+condition * 4);
```

I've no idea what they are doing and how they work. Will someone explain to me? Thank you.

Comment: I do not see anything "*elegant*" here, but just terrible obfuscated code.

Comment: @alk I don't know how to describe it so I picked the word `elegant`. You may replace the title with what you think is appropriate :)

Comment: I actually did not refer to the title of your question but to the title you quote: "*the most elegant way of output I ever met*"

Comment: Referring the title of your question however, I do not see one `<bool-expr>?<expr1>:<expr2>` operation (ternary operator) in the question.

Comment: @alk Well that's the original description of the photo...So there are people who think this is more elegant.

Comment: @alk `i == n?'\n':' '`

Comment: That's not the same as in the question.

Comment: @alk Their intentions are alike IMO

Comment: This does not make the title less misleading. You won't talk about **flying** to the next town if you'd actullay **walk**, although the result is the same: You in this next town, won't you?

Comment: @alk You're right, however I haven't come up with other satisfying titles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`" \n"[i==n]` takes the expression `i==n`, which evaluates to either 0 or 1, and uses it as an index into the array `" \n"`, obtaining either `' '` or `'\n'`.

`"YES\0N0"+condition * 4` takes the array `"YES\0N0"`, which 'decays' to a pointer to its first element when used in most expressions, including this one, and adds `condition * 4` to this pointer. If `condition` is 1, that yields a pointer to the `'N'` at the beginning of `"N0"`.

Answer (score 1):

If `i != n`, a space is printed after `%d`, else a line-feed.

```
//  printf("%d%c", a, " \n"[i==n]);

// when i != n
printf("%d%c", a, " \n"[0]); // or
printf("%d%c", a, ' ');      // or
printf("%d ", a);      // or

// when i == n
printf("%d%c", a, " \n"[1]); // or
printf("%d%c", a, '\n');     // or
printf("%d\n", a);     // or
```

An interesting way to print a number separator, likely use in a `for` loop.

Similar for `puts("YES\0N0"+condition * 4);`

When condition is 0, it prints

```
puts("YES");`
```

When condition is 1, it prints

```
puts("N0");`  // Thanks @ Jonathan Leffler
```

Comment: Strictly nit-picking, it prints `N0` rather than `NO`…

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Right y0u are!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My fault, should be `No` :)

Comment: @laike9m: I know; I'm just teasing you and chux.  The intent was clear; the code didn't quite match the intent, but there wasn't a big problem with the mismatch.  Hence the 'strictly nit-picking' tag.